# Trying to understand CiviAccounts workflow

Tags: developer, hooks, php, financial-accounts

I've read the CiviAccounts Data Flow document and I'm trying to figure out the order things get done.

Here's my situation: My organization collects membership dues at a national level.  But part of those dues are actually local chapter dues.  But not for all chapters.  So I have a table of chapters with their share of the membership dues.  That part works.  But I need to break down the accounting records to reflect both dues, even though the membership form collects only one amount.

For example, if we collect $50 for a person who is from Gotham City, the Gotham City chapter would get $10 of the $50.  I can change the line item record, generate a new line item for the chapter dues and the Financial Item record which references the new line item record.  What I can't figure out is how to set up the Entity Financial Transaction Table to see these new records.  I'm not sure if I can get the financial transaction id yet.  I do all these functions at the civicrm_pre stage for the Line Item record checking for member dues financial type.

So when is the financial Transaction record created for the contribution?  And is it available at the time I'm looking, or do I have to move the breakdown to another timeframe within the complete transaction.